# Facebook Account Kit - SDK more than 7 days old exception

Tags: javascript, facebook, authentication, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I have started using account kit sdk and I have followed proper guidelines. The sdk is hotlinked using the following script tag

`<script src="https://sdk.accountkit.com/en_US/sdk.js"></script>`

But the following error appears on browser's console.

> The SDK is more than 7 days old. Please ensure the AccountKit SDK is
>   hotlinked directly. See
>   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit/integratingweb#configureloginhtml

As a result `AccountKit` stays uninitialized and it fails on `AccountKit.login()` calls.

As sdk is directly hotlinked , I shouldn't be getting this error as per the guidelines. Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: I've got the same issue. Still working for a fix. If I find one I'll post it here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an error on accountkit's side. We cannot do much about it as it was a hotlinked library coming directly from their servers.

The error appeared twice without changing a bit of the code and then it never occurred again.

For anyone else if they face such issue make sure library is hotlinked and if it still occurs then wait for them to fix it, there is no other way.

Comment: I am facing same issue so can please tell me how check library is hotlinked ?

Comment: @MayankVadiya hotlinking is just a buzz word. it means you have used `<script src="https://sdk.accountkit.com/en_US/sdk.js"></script>` in your code, rather than hosting it on your own server. I hope you have already done it.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have the AccountKit init JS code provided inside the Body tag. Otherwise it wont initialise it.